# Infuriated with Android Studio

Tags: html, installation, apk, assets

I have this html code (generated with RocketCake Responsive). It displays fine when I right-click on the file in AS and view in a browser. When I generate the APK and install it on my phone it looks like crap. No images, colours gone, alignment all over the place...??? What is going on...?

Sorry I know its a lot of HTML but maybe there's some experts out there could speed read through or just know straight away what the problem is!

I used to write assembler code so it should be a lot easier than debugging Z80A code on the Sinclair Spectrum...yes that long ago

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <meta name="generator" content="RocketCake">
 <title></title>
 <style type="text/css">
  a { color:#0280E1; } 
  a:visited { color:#0280E1; } 
  a:active { color:#0280E1; } 
  a:hover { color:#B2B3B4; } 
  #table_3933c8cf th { border: 1px solid #8C8C8C;  } 
  #table_3933c8cf td { border: 1px solid #8C8C8C;  } 
  #table_9ea0b09 th { border: 1px solid #8C8C8C;  } 
  #table_9ea0b09 td { border: 1px solid #8C8C8C;  } 
  @media only screen and (max-width: 640px)
  {
    #container_2c8227ab * span { font-size:24pt !important;  }
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#FFFFFF; padding:0;  margin: 0;">
<div style="text-align:center;">
<div style="box-sizing: border-box; vertical-align: top; position:relative;
display: inline-block; width:100%; min-height:150px; background-color:#808080;
border: 10px solid #404040; " id="container_24a694d0"><div style="margin: 10px; display: block; " id="container_24a694d0_padding" >
    <div style="text-align:left;"><div style="vertical-align: top; position:relative; display: inline-block; width:100%; min-height:475px;
    background-color:#5F496D; background: url(instructionbanner.png); background-position:center center; background-size:cover; " id="container_45953828">
        <div style="text-align:center;">  <span style="font-size:12pt; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#000000; "><br/></span>
  <span style="font-size:12pt; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#000000; "><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></span>
  <span style="font-size:26pt; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#FFFFFF; text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.784314); "><br/><br/></span>
  <span style="font-size:12pt; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#000000; ">    <br/><br/><br/><br/></span>
</div>
</div><div style="vertical-align: top; position:relative; display: inline-block; width:100%; background-color:#4B17B0; " id="container_2c8227ab"><div style="margin: 10px; display: block; " id="container_2c8227ab_padding" ><div style="text-align:left;"></div>
<div style="text-align:center;">  <span style="font-size:32pt; font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; color:#C6C699; ">Mirrodin Watch Faces</span>
</div>
</div></div><span style="font-size:32pt; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#20242E; "><br/><br/></span><span style="font-size:15pt; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#20242E; line-height: 1.5; "><br/></span></div>
<div style="text-align:center;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; vertical-align: top; position:relative; display: inline-block; width:29%; min-height:51px; background-color:#FF0000; border: 5px solid #404040; " id="container_16feeedf"><div style="margin: 10px; display: block; " id="container_16feeedf_padding" ><div style="text-align:left;">  <span style="font-size:15pt; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#FFFF80; line-height: 1.5; ">NOTE: REQUIRES WATCHMAKER PREMIUM</span>
</div>
</div></div></div>
<div style="text-align:left;"><span style="font-size:15pt; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#20242E; line-height: 1.5; "><br/><br/> </span></div>
<div style="text-align:center;"><table id="table_3933c8cf" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1"  style="box-sizing: border-box; vertical-align: bottom; position:relative; display: inline-table; width:58%; height:546px; background:none; border: 1px solid #8C8C8C; table-layout: fixed; "> <tr>
  <td width="75%" height="50px" style="vertical-align: top; overflow:hidden; ">  <div style="" id="cell_7b903e14">
    <div style="text-align:right;">
      <span style="font-size:15pt; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#20242E; line-height: 1.5; "><br/>Go to the WatchMaker app.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td width="24%" height="50px" style="vertical-align: top; overflow:hidden; ">  <div style="" id="cell_4c60c1f9">
    <div style="text-align:left;">
      <img src="watchmaker.jpg" style="box-sizing: border-box; vertical-align: bottom; position:relative; display: inline-block; width:34%; background:none; border: 2px solid #404040; " id="img_23c309f5" alt="" title="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td width="75%" height="82px" style="vertical-align: top; overflow:hidden; ">  <div style="" id="cell_44cd065">
    <div style="text-align:right;">
      <span style="font-size:15pt; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#20242E; line-height: 1.5; "><br/>Tap the triple bar menu icon.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td width="24%" height="82px" style="vertical-align: top; overflow:hidden; ">  <div style="" id="cell_1da27e3">
    <div style="text-align:left;">
      <img src="hamburger.png" style="box-sizing: border-box; vertical-align: bottom; position:relative; display: inline-block; width:35%; background:none; border: 2px solid #404040; " id="img_3c75d22f" alt="" title="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td width="75%" height="82px" style="vertical-align: top; overflow:hidden; ">  <div style="" id="cell_688e5a48">
    <div style="text-align:right;">
      <span style="font-size:15pt; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#20242E; line-height: 1.5; "><br/>Tap </span>
      <span style="font-size:15pt; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#20242E; font-weight:bold; line-height: 1.5; ">&quot;My Watches&quot;</span>
      <span style="font-size:15pt; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#20242E; line-height: 1.5; "> on the list under </span>
      <span style="font-size:15pt; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#20242E; font-weight:bold; line-height: 1.5; ">Home</span>
      <span style="font-size:15pt; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#20242E; line-height: 1.5; ">.<br/></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td width="24%" height="82px" style="vertical-align: top; overflow:hidden; ">  <div style="" id="cell_3e4c6bf">
    <div style="text-align:left;">
      <img src="wm my watches.png" style="box-sizing: border-box; vertical-align: bottom; position:relative; display: inline-block; width:92%; background:none; border: 3px solid #404040; " id="img_6631db7e" alt="" title="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td width="75%" height="82px" style="vertical-align: top; overflow:hidden; ">  <div style="" id="cell_261211a2">
    <div style="text-align:right;">
      <span style="font-size:15pt; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#20242E; line-height: 1.5; "><br/>Select the </span>
      <span style="font-size:15pt; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#000000; font-weight:bold; line-height: 1.5; ">WAVY GRAVY</span>
      <span style="font-size:15pt; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#000000; line-height: 1.5; "> </span>
      <span style="font-size:15pt; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#20242E; line-height: 1.5; "> face.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td width="24%" height="82px" style="vertical-align: top; overflow:hidden; ">  <div style="" id="cell_7048c57e">
    <div style="text-align:left;">
      <img src="Wavy Gravy.jpg" style="box-sizing: border-box; vertical-align: bottom; position:relative; display: inline-block; width:34%; background:none; border: 2px solid #404040; " id="img_5353c50c" alt="" title="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td width="75%" height="82px" style="vertical-align: top; overflow:hidden; ">  <div style="" id="cell_6fc79f0f">
    <div style="text-align:right;">
      <span style="font-size:15pt; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#20242E; line-height: 1.5; "><br/>Tap the &quot;Send to Watch&quot;  button.<br/></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td width="24%" height="82px" style="vertical-align: top; overflow:hidden; ">  <div style="" id="cell_3ef5dfa3">
    <div style="text-align:left;">
      <img src="wm send.png" style="box-sizing: border-box; vertical-align: bottom; position:relative; display: inline-block; width:34%; background:none; border: 2px solid #404040; " id="img_68fe4326" alt="" title="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td width="75%" height="111px" style="vertical-align: top; overflow:hidden; ">  <div style="" id="cell_42abcd13">
    <div style="text-align:right;">
      <span style="font-size:15pt; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#20242E; line-height: 1.5; "><br/>The face then appears under the WatchMaker app on your watch.<br/></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td width="24%" height="111px" style="vertical-align: top; overflow:hidden; ">  <div style="" id="cell_14a1b78f">
    <div style="text-align:left;">
      <img src="watchmaker.jpg" style="box-sizing: border-box; vertical-align: bottom; position:relative; display: inline-block; width:34%; background:none; border: 2px solid #404040; " id="img_35ba7929" alt="" title="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table></div>
<div style="text-align:left;"><span style="font-size:15pt; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#20242E; line-height: 1.5; "><br/><br/></span><table id="table_9ea0b09" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1"  style="box-sizing: border-box; vertical-align: bottom; position:relative; display: inline-table; width:77%; height:91px; background:none; border: 1px solid #8C8C8C; table-layout: fixed; "> <tr>
  <td width="100%" height="79px" style="vertical-align: top; overflow:hidden; ">  <div style="" id="cell_65ee0b6b">
    <div style="text-align:left;">
      <span style="font-size:15pt; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#20242E; line-height: 1.5; ">If your watch is already displaying a WatchMaker face </span>
      <span style="font-size:15pt; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#20242E; font-weight:bold; line-height: 1.5; ">WAVY GRAVY </span>
      <span style="font-size:15pt; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#20242E; line-height: 1.5; ">will load immediately and replace the current one.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table><span style="font-size:15pt; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#20242E; line-height: 1.5; "><br/> <br/><br/></span></div>
<div style="clear:both"></div></div></div>  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it RocketCake I shouldn't be using? I'm not competent enough to write complex HTML my self and I haven no Java or C++ experience even though I'd love to make a lovely intro screen. Any suggestions/alternatives?

Thank you everyone.